# Persistence store for state of a job in LUIGI

Tags: luigi

I started with LUIGI recently and had few questions which I was unable to answer myself using [documentation](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html)

Question is regarding state of a job in LUIGI
With Luigi we can set some global configuration (record_task_history) to track history of job and it require to setup a mysql DB. This history can then be later retrieved and shown by luigi visualizer.

1. Are other persistence store supported for this? Can this be done in text files? (Visualizer might not work but am ok with that if I can get historical state programmatically)
2. When does luigi actually write state data to the persistence store? Does it keep it in memory for running job and dump data as soon as job completes?

--learner

Answer (score 0):

1. It supports any store that is supported by SQL Alchemy.
   If you don't use a external store, the state is not saved (only log file). The status of a task is always checked based on the existence of its output.
2. You should check the source code. :D.